# Android app to edit MediaWiki wikis (browser loses data when kicked out of memory)

Tags: android, mediawiki

Let's say I edit a Wikipedia article, and receive a phone call before publishing it. After the phone call, I go back to the browser, and unfortunately it has been kicked out of memory, and I have to re-type everything.

So, I am looking for an Android app that can edit MediaWiki wikis (the software that runs sites like Wikipedia or Wikia).

Requirements:

- What I type is persisted automatically on the phone, I can restart my phone and what I typed is still in the app. For instance I can type a bit, have a phone call, type more, reboot the phone, and then publish.
- Must run on all MediaWiki wikis, not just Wikipedia and Wikia. Possibly using the MediaWiki API.

Bonus for preview or even WYSIWYG.

Comment: Wikicode is just plain text, so what features do you need that a text editor does not have? For instance, do you want to editor to open/save directly from a wiki? Do you want the app to use your wiki username? Do you want preview, or even wysiwyg?

Comment: @Nicolas Raoul I'm looking for an app that let's me edit the famous Wikis (like Wikipedia and Wiktionary and Wikia sites), similar to [Every Wiki](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.nebulium.wiki), but with the ability to edit those Wikis instead of just reading them.

Comment: Wouldn’t "any web browser" be a valid answer here?

Comment: This question is too vague: you can already do that in the web browser. What are your requirements that make the browser unsuitable? Please read our [tips on writing good questions](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: I faced a lot of problems with web browser's editor. For example I can't change the tab because when I return the tab will auto refresh. Not all wikis have a mobile site making editing them with desktop editors hard.

Comment: I improved the question, I believe it should be reopen now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the Android app [wikiEdit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ondrejchrastina.wikieditor), which:

- is free
- supports DokuWiki and MediaWiki
- is an offline wiki editor

[image]

Comment: This is too close to what I'm looking for. I can copy a section or article and edit it in this app and then paste the changes - thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

[WIKIPEDIA mobile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ar.com.hsdcba.android.wiki) is an Android Application.

You need to login to edit a Wiki.

- It allows edit wiki.
- It supports many langues.

> [image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]
>   <sup>Screenshots (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, but this app is just the Wikipedia mobile site.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.